# Regex - Number, character and space only

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript, how do I write a regex expression for numbers (0-9), characters and space only. Characters to include are all the characters with accents etc, not just a to z?

**I had**

```
^[0-9a-zA-ZÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖŠÚÛÜÙÝŸŽàáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöšùúûüýÿž ]*$
```

But there are lot more foreign characters that could be used.

Comment: Be sure to always post a sample of what you tried so far. If you did not try anything, try something first

Comment: @fge I'm assuming javascript as it's tagged. **Edit**: Just saw that the tag was added in an edit, but the text "in javascript" has been there for a while.

Comment: You can try matching a unicode range instead. 
This link shows how to generate a rangeset aswell: http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_cset

Answer (score 1):

I have found it -

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF ]*$
```

This seems to work.

Thanks

Comment: Modified it a wee bit to ^[0-9a-zA-Z\u00C0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF ]*$